# How to write script in BS in siebel to store multiple records in the output?

Tags: crm, siebel

i have a scenario where there is an LOV with High Value as "Package" and TYPE="TO_NEW_PACKAGE" and i have to fetch the value of Low and there are 8 records in Low. I Have to display all the 8 records and their component cost for each record. All this should be gone as a display Message which will be output. Please let me know how to do this.

var sSearchExp = "[Type]= '" + "PACKAGE_PLAN" + "' AND [High] = '" + PACKAGEPLAN + "'"; SetSearchExpr(sSearchExp); ExecuteQuery(); var isRecord = FirstRecord(); while(isRecord) { Slow = GetFieldValue("Low"); Outputs.SetProperty ("NEW_PACKAGE_PLAN",Slow); Outputs.SetProperty("ErrorCode", "00"); Outputs.SetProperty("ErrorDesc", "Success"); i = i+1; isRecord = NextRecord(); }

this is storing only 1 record... i want all the eight records to be displayed!

Comment: Thanks a lot Ranjith. But i output im getting is like property name MSISDN; 0987878784 input and Output Values package plans as Brand1 Prepaid Pack2 Data1 Data2.... Actually.. these are 4 package plans Brand1 Prepaid Pack2 Data1 Data2 I want the output to be properly aligned like this Package Plan:1-> Brand1 :2-> Prepaid  Pack2  :3->Data1 :4-> Data2 Please help with the code.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you started

```
var sSearchExp = "[Type]= '" + "PACKAGE_PLAN" + "' AND [High] = '" + PACKAGEPLAN + "'";
var Slow = "";
SetSearchExpr(sSearchExp);
ExecuteQuery();
var isRecord = FirstRecord();
while (isRecord) {
    Slow += GetFieldValue("Low");
    Slow += " ";
    i = i + 1;
    isRecord = NextRecord();
}
Outputs.SetProperty("NEW_PACKAGE_PLAN", Slow);
Outputs.SetProperty("ErrorCode", "00");
Outputs.SetProperty("ErrorDesc", "Success");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ranjith. But i output im getting is like property name MSISDN; 0987878784  input and Output Values package plans as Brand1 Prepaid Pack2 Data1 Data2....

Actually.. these are 4 package plans 
Brand1
Prepaid Pack2
Data1
Data2

I want the output to be properly aligned like this

Package Plan:

Brand1
Prepaid Pack2
Data1
Data2

Please help with the code

Comment: Hi Ranjith, Can you help me out with this?

Comment: @Niteeshbharadwaj, I mentioned the code was to get you started. Not sure what you meant by alignment. You will have to use spaces and tabs to get the text formatted in way you desire. Try to concatenate with "\t" instead of space and see if that works.

Comment: Sure sir! i would try that. can you please call me on 9676960121 or please give me your number so that i can discuss more explicitly on this

Comment: May i know what is the syntax to be set to store the output? what shoulf be written here Outputs.SetProperty("NEW_PACKAGE_PLAN", Slow);?

Comment: May i know what is the syntax to be set to store the output? what should be written here Outputs.SetProperty("NEW_PACKAGE_PLAN", Slow);? to concatenate or show one output under the other? i have searched but didnot find any

Comment: May i know what is the syntax to be set to store the output? what should be written here Outputs.SetProperty("NEW_PACKAGE_PLAN", Slow) i need to put some seperator

Answer (score 0):

This sample code will print the values downwards:

```
var boAsset = TheApplication().GetBusObject("List Of Values");
var bcAsset = boAsset.GetBusComp("List Of Values");

with (bcAsset)
{
    ActivateField("Value");
    var sSearchExp = "[Type]= 'AAG_TABLE_TYPE'";
    var Slow = "";
    SetSearchExpr(sSearchExp);
    ExecuteQuery();
    var isRecord = FirstRecord();
    while (isRecord)
    {
        Slow += GetFieldValue("Value");
        Slow += "\n";
        isRecord = NextRecord();
    }
    TheApplication().RaiseErrorText(Slow);
}
```

Output:

```
AAG Account
AAG Holdg
AAG Portf
AAG Txn
```

Changing `Slow += "\n";` to `Slow += " ";` will print the values sideways.

Hope you get the trick here.